# Windows phone: calling eventhandlers from backgroundagent notify

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to download an image from a site and make it the background for a tile on WP8.  In my background agent on the OnInvoke() method I have the following lines to download that image into a BitmapImage object:

```
static BitmapImage img;

protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {

                        img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgLoc, UriKind.Absolute));

                        img.ImageOpened += img_ImageOpened;
      });
}
```

However when I step through the code, I never hit the img_ImageOpened events

```
void img_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {

                        Image uiImage = new Image();
                        uiImage.Source = img;
                        CreateNewHubTile(uiImage);
                    });
    }
```

The URI is correct, and I'm able to step to  Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(())... of the OnInvoke() method, it's just the events of the BitmapImage that aren't being called.

I've tried searching google for something, but I don't seem to be using the right keywords... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to disable the delayed creation of the BitmapImage, this is done by setting the CreateOptions to None, like this:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
   Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
          img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgLoc, UriKind.Absolute));
          img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
          img.ImageOpened += img_ImageOpened;
      });
}
```

Also if you have a call to NotifyComplete(), make sure that is not called until you have received your event.

Comment: Bingo, thanks!
I'd vote your answer up, but I don't have enough Reps. Thanks again!